# How to labeling domain and subdomain using python?

Tags: python, url, dns, subdomain

I'm working with url data and i have problem to categorize the url into domain and sub domain using python

I'm trying regex to extract domain but i don't know how to return it into True or False subdomain

for example

```
a = ['facebook.com', 'profile.facebook.com']
```

I expect the result is

```
[False, True]
```

Comment: Your question as is is too broad. If you do not specify specific domain names you work with in all generic cases you can not split into domain/subdomain with just a regex, you need something like the Public Suffix List. Otherwise, for `minefi.gouv.fr`, what is the domain/subdomain? And for `www.dk` ? These are two valid examples where simple regex will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide how loose restrictions you want to put on domain name, rest
can look like:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile('[0-9a-z\.]*\.[0-9a-z]*\.com')
>>> bool(a.match('facebook.com'))
False
>>> bool(a.match('sub.facebook.com'))
True
```

Here I assumed domain will and with `.com` but you can change that too easily.

Comment: what if i have two level subdomain such apps.cs.ipb.com and the top level domain is varies (not only .com)?

Comment: You can check yourself, this regex will still return `True` if you put `sub.sub.domain.com`. To support other top domains you can replace `com` with `(com|net|org)`.

Comment: how about http://2-01-2a40-0015.cdx.cdxcn.net ? it's classified as domain. i change the regex into     ('[0-9a-z:/-0-9a-z\.]*\.[0-9a-z]*\.(com|net|org|id|co.id)') because there is http on the front of url. but maybe my regex is false

Comment: Only addition you need to support dash is `\-` so `'[0-9a-z\.\-]*\.[0-9a-z]*\.(com|net)'` will work for this domain, or if you expect dash in primary domain `'[0-9a-z\.\-]*\.[0-9a-z\-]*\.(com|net)'`

Comment: This regex will match many things that are invalid domain names. It will also fail to match many valid domain names, like those with hyphens.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You are right of course. Proper regex for domain maching was discussed on SO at least few times afair. I could mark this question as duplicate or provide simple example adapted to perceived  question complexity. I only tried to not overcomplicate answer for short question.